# Animal-related alternatives to the 'black swan' expression

Tags: expressions, idiom-requests, synonyms

I am looking for animal-based alternate expressions to the 'black swan' for a rare event (or a rare item, even though that's not precisely what black swan signifies).

I believe I have heard other (and possibly more humorous) animals mentioned in this kind of 'rarity' context, but can't recall which. 
Slang/idioms/colloquialisms ok, some humor preferred (in contrast to 'black swan' connotations).

Comment: *Hen's teeth* refers to rare items.

Comment: [*In Japan, they say that a geisha as such is not a prostitute, yet a virginal geisha is **as rare as a white crow.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22+a+virginal+geisha+is+as+rare%22)

Comment: There's always *purple cow*.

Comment: For infinitely rare, you could use [gone by way of the dodo](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+the+way+of+the+dodo)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Purple cow feels too slapstick, but is in the right vein. I love the white crow expression - never heard that before and it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Vaughn: I didn't mean to imply the simile itself originated in Japan. I've heard it occasionally (UK), but I only just discovered that the first known use was actually [the Roman poet *Juvenal*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7pKp9W--awEC&pg=PA417&dq=%22rare+as+a+white+crow%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMI8MSf473myAIVCTkUCh2RkA2Q#v=onepage&q=%22rare%20as%20a%20white%20crow%22&f=false), almost 2000 years ago. But he was probably just using an established saying anyway. White crows have always existed - rare, but sufficiently striking when they *are* seen to cause talk.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I love that. Thanks for enlightening me!

Comment: @JHCL - 'Hen's teeth' is awesome. My context is more like designating an event or a person AS that unique thing (metaphor rather than simile), and to me, 'person as Hen's tooth' doesn't quite work. I really appreciate the response though, and fully expect to use that phrase elsewhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious (thanks to *Moby-Dick*) term for something rare and elusive is *white whale*—although the albino form of any animal (except laboratory rats and mice) that is normally colored can be used as a metaphor for rareness. For a discussion of rare albino whales (as opposed to mostly white beluga whales) see National Geographic's rather paradoxically title article "[How Did Rare White Whale Spotted Off Australia Get That Way?](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/2015/08/150811-white-whale-humpback-migaloo-oceans-animals-science/)"

Another animal with a famously rare color phase is the [blue lobster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_lobster#Coloration).

Comment: I like that white whales do exist but are rare, unlike (to the best of my knowledge) flying pigs. White crow is a candidate for the same reason. White whale has a bit of a negative/adversarial (Moby Dick) connotation I might try to avoid, but otherwise it's very close. 

REALLY liking the blue lobster notion - perhaps not as well-known culturally, but has a soupçon of inherent humor and might be perfect in my context. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Very broadly used idiom is "[***when pigs fly***"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/when_pigs_fly#English) to mean:

> This phrase is used presumably due to the unlikelihood that pigs will
>   ever evolve wings.
>   (idiomatic) never

[Wiktionary]

You could consider using a "flying pig".

Comment: And tap-dancing elephant.

Comment: @HotLicks How about "skiing rhino"?

Comment: Now it's just getting silly. ;-)

Comment: @Vaughn Nope. It is not silly.

Comment: My first thought was that I nearly always hear this one as *pigs **might** fly*, so I checked Google NGrams. It turns out that there's a big US/UK usage split here. Your version really is [relatively uncommon in BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=when+pigs+fly%2Cpigs+might+fly&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhen%20pigs%20fly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpigs%20might%20fly%3B%2Cc0), but in the last couple of decades it's become the most common form in AmE.

Answer (score 1):

"Black Swan" doesn't mean something rare. It means something that couldn't have been predicted. All swans in the western world are white and people there couldn't have known there were black swans till they heard from Australia. I don't know of animal equivalents.

Comment: Please don't bring facts into the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

A ***rare bird*** :

> - An exceptional individual, a unique person, as in *That wife of yours is a rare bird; you're lucky to have her.*
>
>   - *This idiom, generally used as a compliment, is a translation of the Latin rara avis, which itself was used from about 1600 on and began to be translated only in the late 1800s.*

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: Doesn't a "rare bird" have connotations of "extraordinary", "special", "exceptional", etc.?

Comment: Yes, but also quite rare in that respect, I understand OP is looking for expression similar (not just the same )  to 'black swan.

Comment: I am indeed looking for a similar term. Rare Bird/rara avis isn't a problem in terms of connotation, but the phrase doesn't have quite the humor I am ultimately seeking.

Comment: @Vaughn -         "Black swan" has no humorous connotation about it, but I probably misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Josh61 'Odd Duck' also has some of the rarity and humor, but with less of the positive connotation. Overall I'm looking for neutral or positive (i.e. also not 'perfect storm'-ish). Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: @Josh61 - totally agree re: Black Swan not having humor. My post could have been clearer about my hope of finding that in contrast to 'black swan'.